# Visualising an arrow given pich and yaw?

Tags: android, gps

how to visualise an arrow pointing to a certain position while I change my location.

I mean, while holding my hand-set and moving around I want that arrow to point to a given latitude and longitude

Note: pich and yaw has already been calculated.

Regards,

Comment: did you post the same Q twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700344/how-to-visualise-an-arrow-pointing-to-a-certain-coordinateslatitude-longitude

Answer (score 1):

I've actually just been working on an app to do this as a learning exercise, altho I don't use Pitch and Yaw, just Orientation.

It's at https://github.com/jarofgreen/FindCoords - GPL open source and an apk file available.

Screenshot at https://github.com/jarofgreen/FindCoords/blob/master/screenshot.png