# How to visualise an arrow pointing to a certain coordinates(latitude, longitude), given pich and yaw

Tags: android, math, gps, latitude-longitude, bearing

I would like to know how to visualise an arrow pointing to a certain coordinates(latitude, longitude)
while I'm moving around holding my handset.

I'va calculated the pitch and yaw of the desired position. Now I want to know how to keep pointing to this position while moving.

Regards,

Comment: did you post the same Q twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678415/visualising-an-arrow-given-pich-and-yaw/8700684#8700684

Answer (score 2):

In general you can calculate the bearing angle (the angle between your local meridian and the great circle connecting your current position and the target position measured from the north direction) using this formula:

```
double y = Math.sin(long2-long1)*Math.cos(lat2);
double x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(long2-long1);
double bearing = Math.atan2(y, x);
```

Note that `lat1`, `long1`, `lat2`, `long2` and `bearing` are all in radians. The formula assumes perfectly spherical Earth. See also [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

For more accurate results based on [WSG84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) you can use [android.location.Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)'s [`bearingTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29) method.

Then you can either use compass and draw the arrow at the computed bearing angle to the north-south line or you can assume the north to lie at the top of your phone's screen. The second approach makes a lot of sense if you display a map since most people are accustomed to having north at the top.

Comment: Actually Android provides this in an API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29   
See my answer on duplicate Q :-)

Comment: Thanks, and i would like to clarify more. Actually, I measure the position of a car (lat, long)...and i stored this position and i created a new activity to navigate the user to his car position. I have already obtained the rotation matrix of the car and of the mobile while moving, claculated the distance vector to convert the (lat, long) into (x,y,z) coordinate, calculated the direction vector from the mobile to the car and eventually i obtained the pitch and yaw angles which point to the car position. Now I do not which 1-class should i call to visualise an arrow.

Comment: 2-which class should i call to provide it with the pitch an yaw i calculated so that I can point to the position of the car.

Comment: Indeed and since it is based on WGS84, it is actually more accurate than the above formulae which assume Earth to be perfectly spherical. Thanks, James!

Comment: @Amr Check out the [graphics API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html) and [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html). You may want to obtain an image of an arrow, rotate it by the angle and display it on your control.